Artifacts on Video of 143 images combined into a video by ffmpeg
Left side is from video, and right is original still
The video was created from 143 images from the same camera taken over some months.
Processed using :-
ffmpeg -framerate 1 -pattern_type glob -i '*.JPG' -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
If I play the video in Linux VM on mpv, defect doesn't occur.
If I play it on a W10 machine with either Media player or VLC, I get this on just some frames, maybe 10 randomly through the whole sequence. The defect is always at the same place whenever its run.
Any thoughts on what mystery is occuring?

This video is a little over 4 seconds long?

Each image is shown for 1 second, so video over two minutes. The image above are clipped from the original pic and a single frame with the strange sky effect.

That's an odd occurrence.  Using a filter for fps-vf fps=30 instead of -r is the only thing I can think of to try, really...  That's a strange one.  Maybe it's a colorspace issue in the original JPG files.  Potential workaround, try: for f in *.JPG; do name="${f%.*}"; magick "$f" "$name".png; done and try using .png as the source.
